# GCEインスタンスと手元のPC間でUDP通信をしたい

Tags: python, socket, google-compute-engine, udp

こんにちは、GCEインスタンスと手元のPC間でUDP通信をする方法に関して質問させてください。[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/nadechin/items/28fc8970d93dbf16e81b)を参考に、いろいろ試しているのですが、うまく通信ができておりません。アドバイスいただきたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

## 試している内容

- サーバ：VMインスタンス（OS:Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), f1-micro）

サーバで動かしているコード↓

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import socket
host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" #外部IP、内部IP両方試しました
port = 8088
serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind((host,port))
serversock.listen(10)
print 'Waiting for connections...'
clientsock, client_address = serversock.accept()

while True:
    rcvmsg = clientsock.recv(1024)
    print 'Received -> %s' % (rcvmsg)
    if rcvmsg == '':
      break
    print 'Type message...'
    s_msg = raw_input()
    if s_msg == '':
      break
    print 'Wait...'
    clientsock.sendall(s_msg)
clientsock.close()
```

- クライアント：Cloud Shell

クライアントで動かしているコード↓

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import socket
host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" #外部IP、内部IP両方試しました
port = 8088
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
client.connect((host, port))
client.send("Test Message")
response = client.recv(4096)
print response
```

- ファイアウォールルールの設定に以下の２つを追加しました

  - （上り）ターゲットすべてに適用 IP 範囲: 0.0.0.0/0　udp:0-65535
  - （下り）ターゲットすべてに適用 IP 範囲: 0.0.0.0/0　udp:0-65535
- まずGCE側でサーバ用コードを実行し、「Waiting for connections...」がでてから、Cloud Shellでクライアント用コードを実行しました。

## 困っているところ

- サーバ側は「Waiting for connections...」と出たまま動かない（"Test Message"が表示されてほしい）
- クライアント側は、何も出力されない

## 最終的にやりたい内容

- まずCloud ShellとGCEインスタンスの間でUDP通信ができるようにしたい
- Cloud Shellで動かしているpythonコードを、手元のPC上のJupyterNotebookに移して、手元のPCとGCEインスタンスの間でUDP通信ができるようにしたい

Comment: プログラムが TCP を使っているからでは?
UDP を使いたいなら UDP のサンプルを探すのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP と UDP のメリット/デメリットについてはご存知の上で、UDP 通信をしようと思ってサンプルを動かしてみたが動かなかった、という質問だと思って回答します。

質問のコードは完全に TCP を使ったものであり、UDP 通信ではありません。

質問のコードを元に UDP 向けに変更してみました。
以下のサンプルでいかがでしょうか?

サーバ側:

```
import socket
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8088
serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serversock.bind((host,port))

while True:
    print 'Waiting for data...'
    rcvmsg, rcvfrom = serversock.recvfrom(1024)
    print 'Received -> %s' % (rcvmsg)
    if rcvmsg == '':
      break
    print 'Type message...'
    s_msg = raw_input()
    if s_msg == '':
      break
    print 'Wait...'
    serversock.sendto(s_msg, rcvfrom)
serversock.close()
```

クライアント側:

```
import socket
host = "mike"    # サーバのホスト名
port = 8088
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
client.connect((host, port))
client.send("Test Message")
response = client.recv(4096)
print response
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！いろいろサンプルコードを漁って最後に見ていたものを貼ったのですが事例がTCPのものになってしまっておりました…申し訳ありません。教えて頂いたコードを用いて試してみたのですが、「python xxx.py」というかたちでサーバ側・クライアント側の順に実行しても、サーバ側に"Waiting for data..."は出るのですが、"Test message"などの期待される表示はありませんでした。hostには、外部IPアドレス、内部IPアドレス、ホスト名（今回は"instance-1"）を試してみましたが、上記のような状況でした。お示しいただいたコードで普通はうまくいくはず、ということでしたらGCE上の設定が何か足りないのかと思いますので、そちらも見てみようと思います。

Comment: Cloud shellの代わりに、もうひとつVMを立ててそちらをクライアントにしたら、通信ができました！サーバ側では"host"は内部IP・ホスト名（"instance-1"）は大丈夫ですが、外部IPだとエラーになります。クライアント側で指定するhostは内部IP・外部IP・ホスト名すべてOKでした。同一リージョン内でVMを立てているためホスト名でも通るのではと思っております。おそらくもともとの構成で進めようとすると、CloudShell自体のファイアウォール設定を変える必要があるのかと想像しています。今後、手元のPCに移植しての実装を試してみようと思います。アドバイスをいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

[GCE(Google Compute Engine)のVMインスタンスのアカウントスコープを後から変更する](https://qiita.com/Sekky0905/items/e1ae602a1a2a4edb17df)　の記事は、お読みになりましたか？

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。読んでいなかったので、読みまして、アクセス権が足りないということかと理解いたしました。そこでインスタンスを一旦停止して「Cloud API アクセス スコープ」を「すべての Cloud API に完全アクセス権を許可」に変更してみたのですが、特に状況変わりませんでした。大変恐縮ですが、記事中で私が見落としているところなどありましたら教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。